# Can't find A2DP profile for bluetooth headphone in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, a2dp

My Bluethooth headphones aren't giving stereo output anymore. 
In the sound option I can only see the HSP/HFP profile, the A2DP profile is gone. Why is there no A2DP profile?

Comment: What is the model of your headphones? And as your title says, are you really using Ubuntu 17.10? 18.04 is out, you might like to upgrade.

Comment: actually the problem happened after an software update! After a reboot and disconnecting the bt device and reconnecting solved it. It's alright now.